# How to use macro to automate translation of data in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, database

I'm doing a survey distributed across different countries in different languages.

Hence, I have create individual survey forms in 5 languages (incld English).

I have the dataset in my excel file, different languages in different sheet.

Can i write a macro to automate consolidate all data in english and in single sheet?

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without macros. You can use the Get & Transform (Power Query) tool in the Data ribbon to append data from different sheets into one table. You can find a step by step here: https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/consolidate-multiple-excel-sheets-using-power-query/

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up